# How to pass variables to other PHP files?

Tags: php, terminal

While running one PHP script. The script will call another one somewhere in the script. Those two scripts will need to run simultaneous so I can not use include or require here. The script will be called using the terminal like this:

```
exec( '/usr/bin/php ../process.php >> logs/' . date( 'Y_m_d' ) . '.log 2>&1 &' );
```

The big problem here is I want to process 6 different things, but they will all be using quite the same code. The only difference is the directory where they will be processed in.

Now the question: Is there a simple way to run the second script while passing one or more variables?

I tried something like `../process?var=something`, but this clearly doesn't work this way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can pass some variables as arguments to the script. All the arguments passed are in the variable `$argv`.

See php docs [$argv](http://de.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.argv.php)

Then just loop through the `$argv` and maybe check for some keywords you define.

```
exec( '/usr/bin/php ../process.php -f '/path/to/folder' >> logs/' . date( 'Y_m_d' ) . '.log 2>&1 &' );
```

The `$argv` variable would then hold `-f` and `/path/to/folder`, so just check for `-f` in the loop and get the value by position of `-f`+1.

Comment: Seems like this works. I ran the line with the -f parameter and the output was an array which contains the filename, '-f' and the path.